# ruby start_with?(), end_with?()

Tags: ruby, regex, string-parsing

I have a document with subject headers being enclosed in "|" characters.

E.g. "| LINKS |"

I want to check the string if it begins and ends with "|" character to verify that the particular document's subject header is valid. How do I do so ?

Source:

```
@filetarget = " < document file location here > "

@line = ""

file = File.new(@filetarget)

while (@line = file.gets)
   if((@line.start_with?("|")) and (@line.end_with?("|")))
      puts "Putting: " + @line
   end
end
```

Document text for parsing:

```
| LINKS |

http://www.extremeprogramming.org/  <1>

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExtremeProgramming  <2>

http://xprogramming.com/index.php  <3>

| COMMENTS |

* Test comment
* Test comment 2
* Test comment 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use a simple regular expression:

```
if line =~ /^\|.*\|$/
```

That way you can verify other things, like that the header has to be all caps and needs spaces around it (`/^\|\s[A-Z]+\s\|$/`).

Answer (score 19):

Did you try the [RDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001179)?

```
"| LINKS |".start_with?("|") # => true
"| LINKS |".end_with?("|") # => true
```

Comment: @thotheolh: You should have said so in your question. Was it because you weren't using Ruby 1.9.2? (You can check by doing `puts RUBY_VERSION`)

Comment: Is the 'starts_with' and 'end_with' affected by version ?

irb(main):001:0> puts RUBY_VERSION
1.8.7

Comment: @thoeolh: Yes. I don't think it's available in 1.9.1, or 1.8.7.

Comment: @thotheloh: Both [`start_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000785) and [`end_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000786) are available in 1.8.7. So what exactly did you try? Do you have spaces at the beginning or end of your string? Or maybe a trailing newline?

Comment: You can at the older RDocs by starting from the homepage and navigating through all the frames. I'll bet you a beer that there is a [trailing newline](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/IO.html#M000585) on the string that's messing up the `end_with?` check.

Comment: @mu is too short: And if there's a newline or the like messing things up, the best way to find out is by doing `puts string.inspect` on the string.

Comment: Or by noticing the `File.new("testfile").gets   #=> "This is line one\n"` bit in the fine manual. But `inspect` is a good way to be sure.